# array.filter() removes <falsey> values in a function expression but not in arrow function

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions, function-expression

I'm solving a problem where a function `array_diff` returns values in array`a` that are also in array `b`.

Since I've been learning about named function expressions being better for console debugging than anonymous fat arrow functions, I'm trying to solve this problem with named `removeDuplicate` function to filter my array.

However, I am not able to prevent the filter function from automatically removing the falsey value 0 from my returned array.

Named function expression:

```
function array_diff(a, b) {
  return a.filter(function removeDuplicate(x) { if(b.indexOf(x) == -1) return x; });
}

array_diff([0,1,2,3,4],[2,4]); // [1, 3]
```

Anonymous Fat Arrow function:

```
function array_diffTwo(a, b) {
  return a.filter((x) => { return b.indexOf(x) == -1 });
}

array_diffTwo([0,1,2,3,4],[2,4]); // [0, 1, 3]
```

Can someone explain to me why the falsey value 0 is removed in `array_diff` and not `array_diffTwo`?

Comment: are you sure your example is correct? both look like named anonymous functions.

Comment: because you are returning `0` which is a falsy value, so `if(b.indexOf(x) == -1) return x;` finds `0` in your array and returns it (returns false) then the `0` is removed/filtered out, unlike with `return b.indexOf(x) == -1` which will always return `true` for **0**, **1** and **3** so none of them will get removed/filtered out

Comment: _Anonymous Fat Arrow function_.....I don't see one there.

Comment: I apologize! I did not double check my code. I have edited and shown anonymous fat arrow function :- /

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you `return x` from the filter callback. If `x` (the item being iterated over) is falsey, the result won't be included in the final array, *even if* the `b.indexOf(x) == -1` test is fulfilled.

Do the same thing you're doing with the lower code:

```
return b.indexOf(x) == -1
```

```js
function array_diff(a, b) {
  return a.filter(function removeDuplicate(x) { return b.indexOf(x) === -1 });
}

console.log(array_diff([0,1,2,3,4],[2,4])); // [0, 1, 3]
```

(as a side note, you aren't using arrow functions anywhere in the code)

You could decrease the computational complexity from `O(n ^ 2)` to `O(n)` by creating a Set of `b`, instead of checking `indexOf`s on it on every iteration:

```js
function array_diff(a, b) {
  const bSet = new Set(b);
  return a.filter(function removeDuplicate(x) { return !bSet.has(x); });
}

console.log(array_diff([0,1,2,3,4],[2,4])); // [0, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

you misunderstood the array.filter(`callback`). the `callback` should be a predicate,in the callback you return `true` for the elements you want to keep, `false` for the elements, `not the element`. As you return the elements themselves, that's why the falsey elements are removed.

also, an arrow function should be something like this

```js
array_diff =(a,b)=>a.filter(x=>b.indexOf(x)<0)
console.log(array_diff([0,1,2,3,4],[2,4]))
```